# Tinkerpop & Python - Setting an array property via gremlin

Tags: python, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I'm using JanusGraph with the standard python gremlin binding, and I'd like to set a `float[]` property on a vertex/edge. However, the [Tinkerpop driver for Python](https://pypi.org/project/gremlinpython/) doesn't seem able to do so.

For example, here is an example with a script running directly in Groovy:

```
val = [1.2, 3.4, 5.6]
_client.submit("g.V(4200).property('a', %s as float[])" % val).all().result()
```

And here is the code that fails when using the gremlin python library:

```
val = [1.2, 3.4, 5.6]
g.V(4200).property('a', val).next()
```

Where the error is:

```
GremlinServerError: 500: Property value [[1.2, 3.4, 5.6]] is of type class java.util.ArrayList is not supported
```

The error is probably since requests are serialized in GraphSON by the python driver - and GraphSON supports arrays with elements of varying types, thus the Java code behind the scene reads the value as a `java.util.ArrayList` which indeed cannot be cast to `float[]`.

The question is - is there any sane way to do this, other than writing explicit query strings?

Comment: Also, I know I can bind the python value of the array, instead of formatting it directly. This doesn't make anything work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been discussed a few times and JanusGraph is not the only graph database to have type coercion issues. From TinkerPop's perspective, graphs should either (1) attempt to coerce TinkerPop types to the appropriate type defined in the graph schema or otherwise accepted by the graph or (2) provide additional serialization or other library support to allow for those types to be exposed to their users.

As far as I know, there is no workaround for this other than to use scripts as you have already discovered. Note that JanusGraph already has an [open issue](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1295) for resolving this problem.

Comment: Thanks! At least I now know I'm not missing anything. I'll take a look and see if this is an issue I perhaps can work on.

Comment: It this time it's a catch 22 due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2186